# upload large video with multi-part in AWS S3 bucket with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, swiftui

Everybody, I am looking for uploading large videos (100mb and above) in AWS S3 bucket. I have a SwiftUI iOS Application. I also want to know that what is the correct format to upload for that its will play faster. Is there any special method to play the uploaded video more faster.

This is my code but it is taking lot of time. please help.

```
// MARK: - Upload Video File in Amazon S3 bucket -

func uploadFile() {
    isLoading = true
            
    if title.isBlank {
        showAlert("Empty Title", message: "Title cannot be empty")
        isLoading = false
        return
    }
            
    if caption.isBlank {
        showAlert("Empty Caption", message: "Caption cannot be empty")
        isLoading = false
        return
    }
            
    guard var videoURL = URL(string: url) else {
        showAlert("Alert", message: "Url is not working")
        isLoading = false
        return
    }
            
    let fileName = videoURL.getUniqueFileName()
    let credentials = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: System.AWSS3ACCESSKEY, secretKey: System.AWSS3SECRETSKEY)
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentials)
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
            
    let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityMultiPartUploadExpression()
    expression.setValue("public-read-write", forRequestHeader: "x-amz-acl")
    expression.setValue("public-read-write", forRequestParameter: "x-amz-acl")
    expression.progressBlock = { _, awsProgress in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.progressCompleted = awsProgress.fractionCompleted
            print(self.progressCompleted)
        }
    }
            
    var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityMultiPartUploadCompletionHandlerBlock?
    completionHandler = { _, error in
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
            if error == nil {
                let url = AWSS3.default().configuration.endpoint.url // video  base url
                let publicURL = url?.appendingPathComponent(System.AWSS3BUCKETNAME).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
                print("Uploaded to:\(String(describing: publicURL))")
                if let absoluteString = publicURL?.absoluteString {
                    print("Video URL : ", absoluteString)
                }
            } else {
                isLoading = false
            }
        }
    }
            
    let awsTransferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
            
    awsTransferUtility.uploadUsingMultiPart(
        fileURL: videoURL,
        bucket: System.AWSS3BUCKETNAME,
        key: fileName,
        contentType: "video/mp4",
        expression: expression,
        completionHandler: completionHandler).continueWith { [self] task -> Any? in
        if let error = task.error {
            print("error is: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            isLoading = false
        }
                    
        if let _ = task.result {}
        return nil
    }
}
```